# Subspaces of $ A_{n}(\mathbb {Q})$ in which all nonzero matrices are invertible

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, galois-theory, brauer-groups

Let $A_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $ denote the $n$ times $n$ skew symmetric matrices over the rational number field. Let $N$ be a subspace of  $A_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $.

1. If all the non-zero matrices in $N$ are invertible, what is the maximum the dimension of $N$ can be? You can assume $ n $ is even.
2. Does there exist a subspace $M$ of $A_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $  of dim $ n-1 $ with all the non-zero matrices in $M$ are invertible? You can assume $n$ is even.

Note that if $A_{n}(\mathbb{R}) $ denotes the $n$-times-$n$ skew-symmetric matrices over the real number field, then, for $ n= 4 $ and $ n = 8 $, the answer of the second question is 'yes',  but, for $ n= 6 $, there is no such subspace.

Answer (score 7):

For a field $\mathbb{F}$, let $\mu_\mathbb{F}(n)$ denote the maximal dimension of a subspace $N\subset A_n(\mathbb{F})$ such that all the nonzero elements of $N$ are invertible.  For simplicity, I will assume that the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$ is not $2$.

Then, because $\det(a) = (-1)^n\det(-a) = (-1)^n\det(a^\mathsf{T})= (-1)^n\det(a)$, we have  $\mu_\mathbb{F}(2m{+}1) = 0$.

Meanwhile, clearly, $\mu_\mathbb{F}(2m)\ge 1$, and, as the OP points out, $\mu_\mathbb{R}(4m)\ge 3$ and $\mu_\mathbb{R}(8m)\ge7$ due to the existence of normed division algebras $\mathbb{H}$, of dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{O}$, of dimension $8$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

When $n=2m$, the polynomial function  $\det:A_n(\mathbb{F})\to\mathbb{F}$
is the square of a polyomial
$\mathrm{Pf}:A_n(\mathbb{F})\to\mathbb{F}$ homogeneous of degree $m=n/2$, unique up to a choice of sign.  In fact, $\mathrm{Pf}$ is defined over the integers, $\mathrm{Pf}:A_n(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{Z}$, as a polynomial with integer coefficients with the property that $\mathrm{Pf}(mam^\mathsf{T}) = \det(m)\,\mathrm{Pf}(a)$ for $a\in A_{2m}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $m\in M_{2m}(Z)$.  Consequently, this property holds with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{F}$ for any field $\mathbb{F}$.

It follows that $\mu_\mathbb{R}(4m+2)=1$, since, in this case, $\mathrm{Pf}$ is a polynomial of odd degree, implying that, for any pair $a,b\in A_{4m+2}(\mathbb{R})$, the homogeneous polynomial $p(s,t)=\mathrm{Pf}(sa+tb)$ of odd degree $2m{+}1$ will vanish for some real ratio $[s:t]$.

If $\mathbb{F}$ is an ordered field (more generally, if every nontrivial sum of squares in $\mathbb{F}$ is nonzero), then the standard Clifford algebra construction (using a definite quadratic form) shows that $\mu_\mathbb{F}(n)\ge\rho(n){-}1$, where $\rho(n)$ is the Radon-Hurwitz number.  In particular, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(n)\ge\rho(n){-}1$.  Meanwhile, J. F. Adams has shown that $\mu_\mathbb{R}(n)=\rho(n){-}1$. Thus, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(n)\ge\mu_\mathbb{R}(n)$, but, in general, equality does not hold.

**Claim:** $\quad 2m{-}1\ge\mu_\mathbb{Q}(2m)\ge m$.

In particular, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(6)\ge 3 > \mu_\mathbb{R}(6) = 1$, thus verifying that $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(2m)$ can be strictly greater than $\mu_\mathbb{R}(2m)$.

The claim follows from the fact that the characteristic polynomial of a generic element $a\in A_{2m}(\mathbb{Q})$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
For, when the characteristic polynomial of $a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $I, a, a^2,\ldots, a^{2m-1}$ spans a field $\mathbb{Q}(a)\subset M_{2m}(\mathbb{Q})$, and hence every nonzero linear combination of these matrices is invertible.  Meanwhile, $N(a) = \mathbb{Q}(a)\cap A_{2m}(\mathbb{Q})$ is a vector space with basis $a, a^3, \ldots a^{2m-1}$ and hence has dimension $m$.  Thus, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(2m)\ge m$.

The upper bound follows from the fact that any subspace $N\subset A_{2m}(\mathbb{Q})$ of dimension greater than $2m{-}1$ must intersect nontrivially with the subspace of matrices with the first column equal to zero, since that subspace has codimension $2m{-}1$.

**Remark 1:**  It seems likely that the 'generic' $m$-dimensional subspace of $A_{2m}(Q)$ has all of its nonzero elements invertible, but, perhaps this depends on some carefully defined notion of 'generic'.

**Remark 2:**  Since $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(n)\ge \mu_\mathbb{R}(n)$, the lower bound in the Claim cannot always be strengthened to equality.  For example, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(4)\ge \mu_\mathbb{R}(4) = 3 > 2$. Thus, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(4)=3$.  Similarly, since $\mu_\mathbb{R}(8)=7$, we have $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(8)=7$.  (This answers Question 1 for $n=4$ and $n=8$.)

Note that the OP's Question 2 asks whether $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(2m)\ge 2m{-}1$, presumably provoked by the observation that $\mu_\mathbb{R}(2m) = 2m{-}1$, when $m=2$ and $m=4$.  However, these low dimensions can be very misleading. For all other values of $m$, we have $\mu_\mathbb{R}(2m) < 2m{-}1$, and, in fact, for all but a finite set of values of $m$, we have $\mu_\mathbb{R}(2m) < m$, and in general, as $m$ grows, the lim inf of $\mu_\mathbb{R}(2m)/m$ equals $0$.  On the other hand, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(2m)/m\ge 1$ for all $m$.

**Remark 3:** I'm including this last remark at the request of the OP, but, not being a number theorist, I do not have any realy confidence that this can be turned into a rigorous argument.

I do not know whether $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(6)>3$, however, a  *very heuristic speculation* leads me to suspect that this is true and that it might even be true that $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(6)=5$.

The Grassmannian $G_4(15)$ of $4$-dimensional subspaces of $A_\mathbb{Q}(6)$ is a rational variety of dimension $4\cdot (15-4) = 44$.  Meanwhile, the group $\mathrm{SL}(6,\mathbb{Q})$ has dimension $35$ and it acts on $A_\mathbb{Q}(6)$ via $m\cdot a = mam^\mathsf{T}$ preserving $\mathrm{Pf}:A_\mathbb{Q}(6)\to\mathbb{Q}$.  The induced action of $\mathrm{SL}(6,\mathbb{Q})$ on $G_4(15)$ has generic orbits of dimension $35$, so the 'moduli space' $\mathscr{M}$  of orbits has formal dimension $44-35 = 9$.  Meanwhile, the restriction of $\mathrm{Pf}$ to a subspace $N\subset A_\mathbb{Q}(6)$ is a rational cubic form on $N$, generically nondegenerate.  The moduli of cubic forms of rank $4$ under $\mathrm{GL}(4,\mathbb{Q})$ equivalence has formal dimension $20 - 16 = 4 < 9$, and it is known that there are rational cubic forms of rank 4 that do not represent $0$ rationally.  It *seems* that the map assigning to a generic $4$-plane $N\subset A_6(\mathbb{Q})$ the rational cubic form $\mathrm{Pf}:N\to\mathbb{Q}$ is 'dominant'.  For this reason, it seems likely to me that a 'generic' $4$-plane $N\subset A_6(\mathbb{Q})$ will have the property that $\mathrm{Pf}:N\to\mathbb{Q}$ will not represent $0$ rationally (and hence the nonzero elements of $N$ would all be invertible).

However, it's not that easy to determine whether a given rational cubic forms of rank $4$ represents $0$ rationally, so just choosing a $4$-plane $N$ 'at random' and testing whether its Pfaffian represents $0$ seems to be a very labor intensive way to try to find an example.

All of the above is very speculative, but one could go on to make a similar argument for $5$-planes in $A_6(\mathbb{Q})$.  There, it seems even harder to test for when a given rational cubic form of rank $5$ represents $0$ rationally, though.

Comment: dear @Robert can you explain why  $\mu_{\mathbb{Q} }(n)  \geq \mu_{\mathbb{R}} (n) $? can you give  some example that $\mu_{\mathbb{Q} }(6)= 5 $ or prove that $\mu_{\mathbb{Q} }(6)= 4 $.

Comment: @SugataMandal:  We know that $\mu_\mathbb{R}(n)=\rho(n)$ is achieved in every case by a Clifford algebra construction, and the coefficients of the Clifford algebra are rational (in fact, integral) in a suitable basis. Thus, $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(n)\ge \mu_\mathbb{R}(n)$. As I wrote above, I do not know that $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(6)>3$, so I certainly don't have an example of a $4$- or $5$-dimensional subspace $N\subset A_6(\mathbb{Q})$ such that all of its non-zero elements are invertible.

Comment: dear @Robert I think  $\mu_{\mathbb{R}} (n)= \rho(n) - 1 $ if  your notation $ \rho(n) $ denotes Hurwitzs number . As $ \rho(4) = 4 $ ,$ \rho(8) = 8$ but  $\mu_{\mathbb{R}} (4) =3  $,  $\mu_{\mathbb{R}} (n) =7 $ . I thnik the quaternions and octonions valied for  $ \mathbb{Q} $ also, I cant contruct this type of exmples for other values of $n$ .

Comment: @SugataMandal:  Oh, yes, you are right about the definition of $\rho(n)$.  I should have used $\rho(n)-1$ where I wrote $\rho(n)$ above.  It's not surprising that you can't find other values of $n$ for which $\rho(n) = n-1$ because this only happens for $n=1,2,4,8$, by a famous theorem of Adams.

Comment: Yes @Robert , But I think Adams proved that the result for $ \mathbb{R} $ , I think he used K theory , but it may not be true for the $ \mathbb{Q} $  but we can say that the result is true for $ n=4 $ , $ n= 8 $ , quaternions and octonions valied for ℚ. For the other case I cant find any solid argument..

Comment: @SugataMandal:  I'm not sure what you mean by 'the other case'.  We already know that $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(2m)$ can be strictly greater than $\mu_\mathbb{R}(2m)=\rho(2m)-1$, in fact, this is true almost always.  The Clifford algebra constructions work over any field and with any quadratic form, and $\mathbb{Q}$ admits field extensions of any finite degree (unlike $\mathbb{R}$, which only admits $\mathbb{C}$).  As for normed division algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$, there are infinitely many, but their possible dimensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ are $1$, $2$, $4$, or $8$, as was shown by Dickson.

Comment: dear @Robert Actually  I am interested in my 2nd question ,you already proved that upper bound of $ \mu(n) $ is  n-1,that is true. Actually  I am interested for what values of $n$ it attends this bound , for $ n= 4 $ and $ n= 8 $ it attends this bound  as octonions and quaternion are the example as regular representation of the basis element  (except identity) gives a skew symmetric matrix  .we dont know for the other values of of $n$ , we still couldn't prove this .So I reffer this as an other case.

Comment: @SugataMandal:  OK. I understand.  Certainly, the question of just how large $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(n)$ is an interesting one.  Beyond what I've written so far, I have thought a little about the case $n=6$.   I'm fairly convinced that $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(6)\ge 4$, and I'm even beginning to believe that $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(6)=5$ might be true.  However, if it's true, it depends on some delicate things about rational cubic forms that represent $0$ nontrivially.  Even if this works out, though, I don't have a clue about what might be true for $n>8$.

Comment: dear @Robert you said that  if  $ \mu(6) = 5 $ is true its depend on some delicate things about rational cubic forms that represent 0 non trivially. Can you explain this things be little more. Also you used Clifford algebra to prove lower bound..Can you give some references  of that . It will be very useful for me.

Comment: @SugataMandal:  An excellent reference for Clifford algebras is the book "Spinors and Calibrations" by F. Reese Harvey.  He doesn't specifically treat questions about Clifford algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$, but you can easily show that the structure theorems that he proves for $\mathbb{R}$ continue to work over $\mathbb{Q}$ as long as you use quadratic forms over $\mathbb{Q}$ with discriminant equal to $1$.  As for my speculations about $\mu_\mathbb{Q}(6)$, I'll put in a remark to my answer.

Comment: Okay @Robert thanks for refference , I think  I understand why the $ n $ is the lower bound for $\mu(2n) $ ,That is okay but I cant find my mistake. my question is why does the way to prove $ \mu_{\mathbb{R}}(4n+2)  = 1 $ (you used Pf) not valid for the $ \mathbb{Q} $. Also the the process of clifford algebras over $ \mathbb{Q} $ is right..

Comment: @SugataMandal:  The reason that the argument I give for $\mu_\mathbb{R}(4m+2)=1$ does not work for $\mathbb{Q}$ is that, even though $\mathrm{Pf}$ is a odd degree rational form, that doesn't mean that it has a nontrivial *rational* $0$ on every rational $2$-plane $N\subset A_n(\mathbb{Q})$.  For example, the cubic form $x^3-2y^3$ only vanishes for $x$ and $y$ rational when $x=y=0$.  (Of course, it will have a nontrivial *real* zero, but that's of no use over $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: dear @Robert can u construct in $ A_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $ there is a subspace  N is of $10$ dimensional in which every non zero elements  is of rank strictly greater than $2$ , if such subspace does not exist then $\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}(6)$ does not equal to $5$ otherwise if exists then $\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}(6) = 5 $.

Comment: @SugataMandal:  Unfortunately, I think that finding a 10-dimensional subspace of $A_6(\mathbb{Q})$ such that all its nonzero elements have rank at least 2 is just as hard as finding a 5-dimensional subspace such that all its nonzero elements are invertible.